# wifi card not being detected at all on my laptop

Tags: wireless, 22.04

Just a few days ago, the wifi on my laptop was working just fine. It has went from working just fine, to working every 3 or 4 times I turn the computer on, to not working at all. The wifi switch is on, but the wifi does not turn on at all. All the drivers, including the non-free ones, are installed. I have checked `lspci`. It didn't show up in the list of devices. I have also checked s`udo lshw -C network`. Only the ethernet hardware showed up. I have tried `rfkill list all`, but it gave me nothing. Then I tried `rfkill unblock all`, but nothing showed up either, and it still wasn't working.

Specs:

- Sony Vaio VPCEB35FX
- Intel Core i3
- Intel Centrino Wireless Card
- Xubuntu 22.04

Comment: A recent change with 22.04 was the move from 5.15 (GA) to 5.19 (HWE) if using the HWE kernel stack; I'd try selecting an older kernel (5.15) at grub and see if the issue still occurs... ie switching from the HWE kernel stack to GA maybe an easy option. With Xubuntu, your installation ISO dictates which kernel stack (GA or HWE) you're using by default (*though it can be changed post-install & both kernel stacks can co-exist unless using certain nvidia kernel modules*)

Comment: You might want to physically remove the card from the motherboard and reinsert it, if that doesn't work, it might have failed internally